# How to build jar file for esri geometry-api

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have downloaded `esri-geometry-api` from github and I am trying to get a `jar` file from it using `mvn`.I tried running the following:

```
    D:\lib\geometry-api-java-master>mvn tasks
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-st
aging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Esri Geometry API for Java 1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.702 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-14T09:05:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "tasks". You must specify a valid lifecycle phas
e or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-ar
tifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate,
initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resou
rces, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, gen
erate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes
, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-i
ntegration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site
, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase
NotFoundException
D:\lib\geometry-api-java-master>ls
CONTRIBUTING.md  README.md  license.txt  pom.xml
DepFiles         build.xml  manifest     src
```

I also tried this:

```
    D:\lib\geometry-api-java-master>mvn build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-st
aging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Esri Geometry API for Java 1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.966 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-14T09:07:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phas
e or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-ar
tifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate,
initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resou
rces, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, gen
erate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes
, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-i
ntegration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site
, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase
NotFoundException
```

I have also tried this:

```
    D:\lib\geometry-api-java-master>mvn jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-st
aging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Esri Geometry API for Java 1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.670 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-14T09:08:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "jar". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase
or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-arti
fact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, in
itialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resourc
es, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, gener
ate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes,
test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-int
egration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site,
site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase
NotFoundException
```

Comment: Just try a simple `mvn clean package`. Take a deep look into the docs [about Maven life cylces](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this configuration in your pom.xml

```
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>yourMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

To build a jar try `mvn package`